# When making a line graph, can you start at 4000 on the y axis and then continue up in 500's?

Tags: graphing-functions

When making a line graph, can you start at 4000 on the y axis and then continue up in in the increments of 500? E.g., 4000 at the bottom then, goes up to 4500 then 5000 etc.

Comment: You can do anything you set your scale to man.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as long as it is clear to a viewer that that is what you are doing